# Can telescopic FM/DAB antenna be replaced by Coax?

Tags: antenna, radio, frequency-modulation, coax, coaxial

I tried to search for this prior to asking but with no luck...

I have an FM/DAB+ antenna like this:

[image]

from which a standard 75-Ohm Coax is coming down and I would like to connect it to the radio (Panasonic RX-D70BT) like this:

[image]

as you can see there is only an AC-IN plug and a typical telescopic antenna (no other slots) so the idea is to unsolder that telescopic antenna and solder the Coax instead of it. will this work (?) or am I completely on the wrong track? for some reason I have a feeling this won't be that easy, but I am happy to learn it.

Comment: The telescoping antenna most likely connects with a single conductor. Your coax has two conductors, and connects to an antenna with two connection points.

Comment: what is the reason for doing this?

Comment: @jsotola the end goal is to listen to the radio which is in the basement where there is no reception and the external FM/DAB+ antenna is on the roof from where the coax runs to the basement.

Comment: do you have ligtning arrestors installed?

Comment: @jsotola yes, I do.

Comment: since the coax is already installed then touch the center conductor to the antenna on the radio ... it may work

Comment: A passive FM/DAB antenna can be used for something else like tissues used as toilet paper however with their own characteristics. The cable (and connector) is used to transport /connect the signal. To figure out it will work, you need to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a good chance of success. But you need to find an internal ground point in the radio, besides the antenna connection.

Open the radio up and look for a large copper area on the PCB, or some large metal shields soldered to the PCB. The closer to the antenna lead, the better.

If you have a soldering iron, you can solder short wires to the antenna connection and ground, then connect them to your incoming coaxial cable. It would be best to install an actual coaxial connector. Disconnect it if there's any risk of an electrical storm.

If you don't have a soldering setup, you can still "hack" your way forward. Unscrew the pivot point of that telescoping antenna, remove the telescoping part, and put the coax center conductor under the screw and retighten. For ground, slip a wire under the negative end of one of the batteries, or just wrap it around the battery clip.

Because that antenna has the center conductor at DC ground, there's little chance of lightning or static coming down the center conductor, rather than the shield. But you must have the coax shield connected to a good ground where it enters the house.

Comment: I would be wary of connecting the inner conductor of the coax to the whip antenna connection and the shield of the coax to ground without investigating the circuit further, especially to determine if the antenna is isolated by a capacitor. By the looks of it, the OPs dipole antenna is "folded", i.e. is a short at DC.